# Detect modal dialogs with WMI

Tags: wmi

Is there any way to detect open windows or more specifically open modal dialogs with WMI calls?  I've been able to get a list of the processes through Win32_Process, but this does not have any information about the windows that the processes have open.  I specifically mention WMI because the solution must be able to get information from a remote machine without having anything I'm building installed on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not any WMI class related to Dialogs or Windows.